# rest api dynamic json building, i'm trying to get "parent_codes": ["63"],below response is giving line breaks

Tags: rest-api, json, jsongenerator

```
{
    "description": "Core",
    "code": "Core",
    "Active": true,
    "category_Type": "campaign_category",
    "parent_codes": [
        "63"
    ],
    "parent_Type": "sub_brand"
}
```

here i'm trying to get "parent_codes": ["63"],

Apex code:

```
list<CM_CP_Reference_Data__c> refObj=[SELECT Parent_code__c, Description__c, Is_Active__c, Code__c,Parent_Description__c,Category_Type__c,Category_Type__r.name, Id, Name FROM CM_CP_Reference_Data__c where Category_Type__c IN:refrenceDatasetids.keySet()];
    if(refObj!=null){
        JSONGenerator RefDataRespGenerator = JSON.createGenerator(true);
        for(CM_CP_Reference_Data__c refDtataObj : refObj){
            if(refDtataObj.Parent_code__c!=null){
                RefDataRespGenerator.writeFieldName('parent_codes');
                RefDataRespGenerator.writeStartArray();
                for(String arrayRec : refDtataObj.Parent_code__c.split(';')){
                    RefDataRespGenerator.writeString(string.valueOf(arrayRec) );
                }
                RefDataRespGenerator.writeEndArray();
            } 
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add **writeStartObject** and **writeEndObject** in JSONGenerator object. Check below code, it should work.

```
JSONGenerator RefDataRespGenerator = JSON.createGenerator(true);
RefDataRespGenerator.writeStartObject();
for(CM_CP_Reference_Data__c refDtataObj : refObj){
    if(refDtataObj.Parent_code__c!=null){
        RefDataRespGenerator.writeFieldName('parent_codes');
        RefDataRespGenerator.writeStartArray();
        for(String arrayRec : refDtataObj.Parent_code__c.split(';')){
            RefDataRespGenerator.writeString(string.valueOf(arrayRec) );
        }
        RefDataRespGenerator.writeEndArray();
    } 
}
RefDataRespGenerator.writeEndObject();

String jsonString = RefDataRespGenerator.getAsString(); 

System.debug('===jsonString===='+jsonString);
```

Answer (score 0):

JSON is actually not native to server languages like Apex and so its much more confusing when working on them in server languages. Instead of using JSON generator, you can simple use `serialize` on that standard data-types of Apex, to get the JSON. You can check below code:

```
list<CM_CP_Reference_Data__c> refObj=[SELECT Parent_code__c, Description__c, Is_Active__c, Code__c,Parent_Description__c,Category_Type__c,Category_Type__r.name, Id, Name 
                                          FROM CM_CP_Reference_Data__c 
                                          where Category_Type__c IN:refrenceDatasetids.keySet()];

    List<String> parentCodesList = new List<String>();

    for(CM_CP_Reference_Data__c acc : refObj){
        parentCodesList.add(acc.Parent_code__c);
    }
    String parent_codes = JSON.serialize(new Map<String,List<String>>{'parent_codes'=>parentCodesList});
    System.debug(parent_codes);
```